# C preprocessing fails to stop immediately after an #error

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, c-preprocessor, avx

My question today should not be very much complicated, but I simply can't find a reason/solution. As a small, reproducible example, consider the following toy C code

```
#define _state_ 0

#if _state_ == 1
int foo(void) {return 1;}
#else

/* check GCC flags first
   note that -mfma will automatically turn on -mavx, as shown by [gcc -mfma -dM -E - < /dev/null | egrep "SSE|AVX|FMA"]
   so it is sufficient to check for -mfma only */

#ifndef __FMA__
#error "Please turn on GCC flag: -mfma"
#endif

#include <immintrin.h>  /* All OK, compile C code */
void foo (double *A, double *B) {
  __m256d A1_vec = _mm256_load_pd(A);
  __m256d B_vec = _mm256_broadcast_sd(B);
  __m256d C1_vec = A1_vec * B_vec;
  }
#endif
```

I am going to compile this `test.c` file by

```
gcc -fpic -O2 -c test.c
```

Note I did not turn on GCC flag `-mfma`, so the `#error` will be triggered. What I would expect, is that compilation will **stop immediately** after GCC sees this `#error`, but this is what I got with GCC 5.3:

```
test.c:14:2: error: #error "Please turn on GCC flag: -mfma"
 #error "Please turn on GCC flag: -mfma"
  ^
test.c: In function ‘foo’:
test.c:22:11: warning: AVX vector return without AVX enabled changes the ABI [-Wpsabi]
   __m256d A1_vec = _mm256_load_pd(A);
           ^
```

GCC does stops, but why does it also pick up a line after `#error`? Any explanation? Thanks.

---

For people who want to try, there are some hardware requirement. You need an x86-64 with `AVX` **and** `FMA` instruction sets.

Comment: Older versions of gcc certainly used to abort compilation on `#error`, so it's unclear if this is a feature or a regression

Comment: I'm saying that IDK whether the gcc devs did this on purpose for some reason, or if it is a compiler bug

Comment: It's generally considered more useful for a compiler to report **all** errors, not just the first one, so you can fix all the problems before compiling again.

Comment: Unfortunately, when there are errors due to a dependency, the first error can cause a cascade of other errors, which can be annoying. But you can't have it both ways.

Comment: There is a 5yo [feature request](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48839) to change the behavior.

Comment: @Barmar `#error` indicates that the coder intentionally wanted compilation to stop because something went wrong with the compiler configuration . Like a compile-time assert. Any subsequent messages are useless.

Comment: @M.M That's not necessarily true. The C99/C11 standards do not provide a `#warning` directive, and things like `#pragma message` are compiler-specific extensions. So for "ideal" portability, `#error` has to do double-duty. Furthermore, it is possible to abort preprocessing by wrapping the code following the error in an `#ifndef MY_ERROR_HAPPENED ... #endif` block. The converse, forcing continuation of preprocessing after a directive (ex: `#error`) halts, is simply not possible. Thus, I prefer the "don't halt" behavior: it provides the greatest number of possibilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a draft copy of the C ISO spec, and in §4/4 - it states

> The implementation shall not successfully translate a preprocessing translation unit containing a #error preprocessing directive unless it is part of a group skipped by conditional inclusion.

Later on, in §6.10.5, where `#error` is formally defined, it says

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>   `# error pp-tokens opt new-line`
>   causes the implementation to produce a diagnostic message that includes the specified
>   sequence of preprocessing tokens.

In other words, the spec only requires that any code that has an `#error` just needs to fail to compile and report an error message along the way, not that the compilation immediately needs to terminate as soon as `#error` is reached.

Given that it's considered good practice to always check the top-level errors reported by a compiler before later ones, I'd imagine a competent programmer who saw a string of errors beginning with an `#error` directive would likely know what was going on.

Comment: This is a quality of implementation issue... it would also be conforming if the compiler responded to any error with the message "ha ha your program is bad"

Comment: @M.M I could imagine a reasonable compiler author choosing to continue compilation to report any other errors it encounters in case there are other problems with the source file, though you're right that it's probably not the best call.